# Permission denied for image upload on Django rest wsgi with apache2

Tags: django, ubuntu, django-rest-framework, apache2, wsgi

#### Main problem

When user uploads image to the rest admin portal, permission error is thrown. The backend model is a simple one with only `ImageField` and `TextField`.

#### My setup

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Python 3.6

Apache2 with mod_wgsi compiled for python3.6

The upload destination is owned by my account and wwwdatagroup(I created this group for www-data and grant 760 on the upload destination)

Here is the output of `ls -l` This folder is under my home directory, the image is uploaded to a subfolder of media folder.

```
drwxrw---- 3 MYUSERNAME wwwdatagroup 4096 Jul 30 17:48 media
```

This was set by `chmod -R 760 media` I suppose this will set the permission recursively.

#### Question

My wsgi process has no specific user set, so it should run under the user which apache is running on. In my case `www-data`. As shown above, obviously this folder and all is subfolders can be read, written(rw) by wwwdatagroup which contains www-data. So WHY PERMISSION DENIED?

#### Help...

I am staring at the error page and crying. Real tears.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting `770` for `wwwdatagroup` on the media folder. My guess is that Django is doing some listing(require `x` permission) or trying to mkdir(this requires `x` too? I don't know).

I will keep this question open and will give the accepted answer to person who explains this well. Thanks!